# Variable ID in referrer URL

Tags: php, arrays

I want to check if the referrer is on of the valid URLs declared in an array:

```
$ref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

$ref_arr = array (
    SITE_URL . 'nouvelle-annonce/',
    SITE_URL . 'nouvelle-annonce/matieres/',
    SITE_URL . 'nouvelle-annonce/lieu/'
);

if ($ref == '' || !in_array($ref, $ref_arr)) {
    // Fail
} else {
    // Pass
}
```

Now, in the array I want to add something like:

```
SITE_URL . 'annonce/***/modifier/matieres/
```

Where *** is a number (1 to let's say 1000000).

How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use regexp.

```
$pattern = "/^(annonce\\/)([\\d]{1,3})/"; 
$ref = "annonce/999/modifier/matieres/"; 
preg_match($pattern, $ref, $matches);
```

Then you can use IF in_array OR preg_match..

Answer (score -1):

Done, here is what I'm looking for:

```
$ref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

$ref_arr = array (
    SITE_URL . 'nouvelle-annonce/',
    SITE_URL . 'nouvelle-annonce/matieres/',
    SITE_URL . 'nouvelle-annonce/lieu/'
);

if (isset($_GET['annonce-id'])) {
    $ref_arr[] = SITE_URL . 'annonce/' . $_GET['annonce-id'] . '/modifier/matieres/';
    $ref_arr[] = SITE_URL . 'annonce/' . $_GET['annonce-id'] . '/modifier/lieu/';
}

if ($ref == '' || !in_array($ref, $ref_arr)) {
    // Fail
} else {
    // Pass
}
```

Comment: If that's the answer, then your question wasn't clear.